# C# List<> Intitialized with Count 1 and null in the first position

Tags: c#, list

[image]I have a list in a base class where I initialize it as so:

```
  protected List<T> _list = null;
   #region Overrides

    public override DataTable YieldTable()
    {
        DataRow[] cln = new DataRow[_list.Count];
        T bob;
        DataRowCollection item;
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            bob = _list[i];
            item = bob.YieldTable().Rows;
            if (item.Count > 0)
                cln[i] = item[0];
        }
        DataTable tbl = cln.CopyToDataTable();
        return tbl;
    }

    public override string ToCSV(bool includeHeader = true)
    {
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        int n;
        T item;

        if (_list == null || _list.Count < 1)
        {
            _list = new List<T>(1);
            _list.Add(default(T));
        }
        i = 0;
        n = _list.Count;
        //item = _list[0];
        //csv.AppendLine(item.ToCSV());
        for (i = 0/*1*/; i < n; i++)
        {
            item = _list[i];
            csv.AppendLine(item.ToCSV(includeHeader));
            if (includeHeader) includeHeader = false;
        }
        return csv.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToCSV();
    }

    #endregion Overrides
  protected  void DoInitializeCollection()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }
```

If I put a break point on the call to "new" and let that run it runs fine with no exception. I see when I put the cursor over "_list" after the call to new intellisense tells me that "_list" has a count of 1. When I view the locals window I see element [0] in that list with value of null. I have tried _list.Clear(), _list.RemoveAt(0) _list.RemoveAll(predicate) and none of that worked. The calling code breaks because it tries to get a hold of the first element in the list and expects an object to call methods against. I get the familiar "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception because the first element is "null".

Here is the entire class file contents

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace AIMS.Objects
{
static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T :    
ICloneable
    {
        return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}

public class BusinessCollectionBase<T> : BusinessObjectBase where T : BusinessObjectBase
{

    #region Variables

    protected List<T> _list = null;

    #endregion Variables

    #region Constructors

    public BusinessCollectionBase(int capacity)
    {
        _list = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    public BusinessCollectionBase()
    {
        DoInitializeCollection();
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_list == null || i < 0 || i >= _list.Count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Attempt to read internal list at location " + i.ToString());
            return _list[i];
        }
        set
        {
            if (_list == null || i < 0 || i >= _list.Count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Attempt to write internal list at location " + i.ToString());
            _list[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public List<T> InternalList
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (_list == null)
                return 0;
            return _list.Count;
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region API

    public void SortById()
    {
        _list.Sort((x, y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));
    }

    #region Static

    protected static DataRowCollection Get(string sp, Dictionary<string, string> parms)
    {
        DataTable cln = BusinessObjectBase.GetDataTable(sp, parms);

        return cln.Rows;
    }

    protected static DataSet Set(string sp)
    {
        DataSet ds = BusinessObjectBase.GetSet(sp);

        return ds;
    }

    #endregion Static

    #endregion API

    #region Overrides

    public override DataTable YieldTable()
    {
        DataRow[] cln = new DataRow[_list.Count];
        T bob;
        DataRowCollection item;
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            bob = _list[i];
            item = bob.YieldTable().Rows;
            if (item.Count > 0)
                cln[i] = item[0];
        }
        DataTable tbl = cln.CopyToDataTable();
        return tbl;
    }

    public override string ToCSV(bool includeHeader = true)
    {
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        int n;
        T item;

        if (_list == null || _list.Count < 1)
        {
            _list = new List<T>(1);
            _list.Add(default(T));
        }
        i = 0;
        n = _list.Count;
        //item = _list[0];
        //csv.AppendLine(item.ToCSV());
        for (i = 0/*1*/; i < n; i++)
        {
            item = _list[i];
            csv.AppendLine(item.ToCSV(includeHeader));
            if (includeHeader) includeHeader = false;
        }
        return csv.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToCSV();
    }

    #endregion Overrides

    #region Virtual

    protected  void DoInitializeCollection()
    {
        _list = new List<T>(0);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public virtual void AddRange(BusinessCollectionBase<T> bob)
    {
        foreach (T b in bob.InternalList)
        {
            this.InternalList.Add(b);
        }
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetDistinct(string byField, bool sortItToo = false)
    {
        if (_list == null)
            return new List<T>();
        ArrayList uniqueVins = new ArrayList();
        List<T> newList = new List<T>();
        foreach (T t in _list)
        {
            if (t._properties[byField] != null && !uniqueVins.Contains(t._properties[byField]))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t._properties[byField].ToString()))
                {
                    uniqueVins.Add(t._properties[byField].ToString());
                    newList.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
        if (sortItToo)
        {
            // This shows calling the Sort(Comparison(T) overload using  
            // an anonymous method for the Comparison delegate.  
            // This method treats null as the lesser of two values.
            newList.Sort(delegate(T x, T y)
            {
                if (x._properties[byField] == null && x._properties[byField] == null) return 0;
                else if (x._properties[byField].ToString() == null) return -1;
                else if (y._properties[byField].ToString() == null) return 1;
                else return x._properties[byField].ToString().CompareTo(y._properties[byField].ToString());
            });
        }
        return newList;
    }

    #endregion Virtual

    #region Helper Methods

    protected List<T> FilterOut(Predicate<T> p)
    {
        if (this.Count < 1)
            return null;
        List<T> filtered = _list;
        filtered.RemoveAll(p);

        return filtered;
    }

    #endregion Helper Methods
}
```

}

Comment: Please take a screenshot of the locals window and add it to your question. Also I can not re-create your problem with the code you have provided.

Comment: Please show the base class and the derived. something is initializing it differently.

Comment: As-is your problem is not reproduceable. You need to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question or else your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Screenshot added as per Scott Chamberlains request

Comment: #region Overrides added at aNerd's request. But really, there is nothing there to help.

Comment: I should also add that even right after _list is initialized to "null" with this line protected List<T> _list = null; it still has a count of 1 with null sitting in the [0] slot. I am only posting this because I have never seen anything like this in the past and it defies what I thought I knew of C#!

Comment: Well this seems like the obvious culprit unless I'm missing something: `_list.Add(default(T));`  `default(T)` will be `null` if `T` is a reference type. You are adding a null object to the list - when the callers grab the first item and call methods on it it gets an NPE.

Comment: D Stanley, but I don't have that except in the ToCSV method which was not invoked. This error is occurring in an ASP.Net application right on startup

Comment: Can you show the context of the call to  DoInitializeCollection(), what type do you use it with?

Comment: Do you have a type called `List<T>` in your project? Does the behavior change if you replace every `List<T>` with `System.Colletions.Generic.List<T>`? Do you do any multi-threading in your app?

Comment: The Call to DoIntializeCollections is simply invoke by the constructor. That is all the ctor does: 
        public BusinessCollectionBase()
        {
            DoInitializeCollection();
        }

Comment: I added the entire contents of the class file appended at the end. The derived class has this signature: public class Companys : BusinessCollectionBase<Company>
    {

Comment: The constructor of Companys (derived from BusinessCollectionBase) that takes in a DataRowCollection goes on to call the constructor in BusinessCollectionBase which in turn calls DoInitializeCollection method which is where the problem is happening. 
        public Companys(DataRowCollection companies)
        {
Here is the stack trace:
             Objects.BusinessCollectionBase<Objects.Company>.BusinessCollectionBase() Line 35 C#
> Objects.Companys.Companys(System.Data.DataRowCollection companies) Line 16 + 0x8 bytes C#

Comment: Maybe you just run not the same version of code you debug with?

Comment: Scott: I don't implement my own version of List<T>

Comment: I can confirm that list is initialised with first value null at the very call of the constructor even before DoInitializeCollection is called. Also internalList is initialised the same way and Count is 1.

Comment: Scott: this is an intermittent failure. It was working alright at first when I made that change but now its back to its errorful ways.

Comment: The problem is in the following code: if (this._list == null || this._list.Count < 1)
            {
                this._list = new List<T>(1);
                this._list.Add(default(T));
            } in the ToCSV method.After commenting it the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:
Overriding `ToString()` and initialising a property in the `ToString()` method
initializes the property right when you call the constructor, because an object is created and the object creates its string representation immediately.
In your code you call the method `ToCSV(bool includeHeader)` from `ToString()` and that is where the initialization of the `_list` property happens.
You need to export this logic in other method not called by `ToString()`.